# R: How to create two variable using if else condition

Tags: r

Let's say I have dataset contain two variable-

```
Name              Name2
Dr John           Apollo Hsp
AIIMS Hsp      Dr Khan
```

Now I want create two more variable based on condition when name start with Dr that will go to physician column and when it not start with Dr it will go to facility column.

**Output:**

```
Name              Name2           facility            Physician
Dr John           Apollo Hsp.   Apollo Hsp.   Dr John
AIIMS Hsp      Dr Khan.        AIIMS Hsp.    Dr Khan.
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `ifelse` here with `grepl`:

```
df <- data.frame(Name=c("Dr John", "AIIMS Hsp"),
                 Name2=c("Apollo Hsp", "Dr Khan."), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df$facility  <- ifelse(grepl("^Dr", df$Name), df$Name2, df$Name)
df$Physician <- ifelse(grepl("^Dr", df$Name), df$Name, df$Name2)
df

       Name      Name2   facility Physician
1   Dr John Apollo Hsp Apollo Hsp   Dr John
2 AIIMS Hsp   Dr Khan.  AIIMS Hsp  Dr Khan.
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks Tim, 
Is it possible to use if else condition to create two variable. As I have many condition like.... Dr, MD etc

Comment: I don't see an obvious way to extend your logic here.  You might want to open a new question.